# Should Front End Engineers/Designers be "decently" aware of the Rich set of User Controls that are provided by frameworks like .NET, Java, RoR etc.?

Tags: .net, frontend, rich-internet-application

Should Front End Engineers/Designers be "decently" aware of the Rich set of User Controls that are provided by frameworks like .NET, Java, RoR etc.? This would help convert designs into actual code by Developers a more elegantly as the design would be in the native controls provide by the Framework being used instead of vanilla HTML/CSS/JS?

A manager friend of mine( :-) )ask this question to me, I thought it will be a good idea to have your views on this. Feel free to write back your opinions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think this is a question better suited to http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

My experience of working with many front end developers is that the good ones (in my experience) love to get involved as much as possible with the features available to them.

Whether or not a front end developer "should" or "should not" involve themselves and be aware of the underlying technology is a question for philosophers and academics. My experience is that those people who want to be involved and want to learn more, are the ones I love having on my team.